# HTML head block too big

Tags: php, html, iis-7

I am experiencing an issue. I would like to take my HTML "head" block, and have it load on every page. I am using IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I'm trying to find a way to have something like

```
    <link rel="header" href="mywebsite.com/src/header.html" type="text/html" />
```

or something like that, on every page, instead of one massive block. anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are you really running PHP on IIS?  Do you want to do this with html files or php files?

Comment: @gilly3, PHP on IIS is a very common configuration.

Comment: @Brad - Fine, but it still matters.  There's a PHP answer and an IIS answer.

Answer (score 1):

use php to include the head  :

```
<?php
      include "mywebsite.com/src/header.html";
?>
```

put it at the beginning of every file

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend solving this in your web server so the fact that you are using IIS doesn't matter much even though many will tell you its not the ideal choice.

There are many back-end frameworks such as symfony, rails, meteor and others which use templating engines (handlebars, jade, Twig) that automatically place files in your head according to their physical location.
In some, like Twig of Symfony2 you can use a template inside head and have a separate file with your head declarations a bit like you present it above..

In addition to that you can use server side or client side aggregators such as the Yahoo one. (yui min) These tools will concatenate your JS and CSS files into one therefore reducing the total number of files and your head in total.

If you are using PHP then Symfony2 might be the solution for you as it offers all the above.

Comment: Solved by your web server: [Configure IIS 7 for server-side includes](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/serversideinclude)